# Integrate blog into Android application

Tags: android

I want to convert my blog into the responsive Android application with my custom theme. I just don't want to load that **URL** into my android application **Webview** but also I want to set my custom theme into my android application. Can I achieve that? If yes, how can I achieve it?

Comment: Well, I don't think this qualifies as an answer, but on the other hand, there isn't much more to say, I think. So...To use your custom theme, you have to create a new XML Layout for an app, as you can't simply hit a convert button. If you want to load your blog articles directly int your app, you have to get it from the database, where your blog also stores them. So, to achieve your goal is the first question: Have you access to the server, your blog is hosted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way you have to do that is with a RSS reader.

There you have a Youtube Playlist with an step by step Tutorial. Easy to follow.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=19NSla4FNdQ&list=PLOvzGCa-rsH-9QjlFBVHfBNUzPGHGzj-5&index=1

I just follow this tutorial last weekend and works perfectly.

Hope it helps!